# How does the lambda function work in series.replace

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm learning python and can't understand how the lambda function uses the regex first argument of replace to perform the slice of the subgroups to use as the second argument.

How does x becomes the subgroups?

Or is that not the case...... Any simple and clear explanation for a beginner will be greatly appreciated.

```
df['text'].str.replace(r'(\w+day\b)', lambda x: x.groups()[0][:3])
```

Comment: Have you checked the documention for `replace`?

Answer (score 0):

It’s `groups()` function that returns subgroups, lambda is just way to generate function object. The main difference between def and lambda is that instead assigning the function object to some name as in `def some_name(): pass`, lambda just returns the function.

In your case please note that x is a re.Match object. Its method - groups() - returns a tuple of string caught by the capturing group `(\w+day\b)`. This is easy to observe by just printing insides of the lambda function. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Monday', 'Tuesday']})

df['text'].str.replace(r'(\w+day\b)', lambda x: print(x))
```

output: re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='Monday'

re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='Tuesday'

```
df['text'].str.replace(r'(\w+day\b)', lambda x: print(x.groups()))
```

output: 
('Monday',)
('Tuesday',)

Details in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.match.groups).